# drumjs as a Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I'm trying to create a Menu which should have the looks as datepicker from IOS7. At this very moment I am using the plugin drumjs, which would resemble that look.

Then again while testing the plugin as a menu, I've came to some issues. One of these would be that i can't add a hyperlink to the options. Nor through html or javascript.

The reason for this would be since drumjs hides the current menu and replaces it with a self structed one.

My question now is, how can i use this and place the hyperlinks on each of the following options?

HTML:

```
<select >
        <option onChange="menuLink()" value="http://www.google.com">MISSION</option>
        <option onChange="menuLink()" value="http://www.slysolutions.ch">PAUL</option>
        <option onChange="menuLink()" value="2">EXPERIENCE</option>
        <option onChange="menuLink()" value="3">ABOUT US</option>
    </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function menuLink (){
    window.location = "http//www.google.ch";
}
```

Explanation what i tried with javascript. Was if he would react if i would change the option. This of course didn't work.

Comment: `<select onchange=menuLink(value)>` ... `function menuLink (u){
window.location =u;}`

Comment: I tried that before. The only thing it did was create two different types of select bar nothing else.